# How can I create or mimic file-static variables in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, static, static-variables

I want to create a file-static variable in PHP. How can I do this or what should I use instead?

Edit:

I'm basically wanting to create a file-scope static variable, similar to what is available in C/C++.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like a variable that is only global for a single file.  For what purpose do you want this?

Comment: I mean, if it's *really* necessary you could create some sort of class with a static variable that is an array based on the filename (passed in with `__FILE__`, but I can't see that actually being useful. Maybe for some weird debug utility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, it seems like the easiest solution is to just use a class which wraps the functions. The only downside is you have to use the prefix when calling: `Container::Func();`
This could be solved with an additional wrapper for each function, but this isn't as clean of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at namespaces. Available only in PHP >=5.3
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

Comment: PHP namespaces can not contain variables according to the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287315/can-php-namespaces-contain-variables