# Can PHP namespaces contain variables?

Tags: php, variables, namespaces

Can PHP namespaces contain variables? If so, how can this be accomplished?

Comment: Have you tried?  If you have tried, what was the outcome?

Comment: @Charles Or he could ask, get a proper answer and help future readers with it... instead of everyone having to "try it out" themselves.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

No. You can set a variable after declaring a namespace, but variables will always exist in the global scope. They are never bound to namespaces. You can deduce that from the absence of any name resolution descriptions in

- [FAQ: things you need to know about namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php) (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)

There would also be no allowed syntax to locate variables in a namespace.

```
print \namespace\$var;      // syntax error

print "${namespace\\var}";  // "unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR"
```

Answer (score 27):

Try this

```
<?php
namespace App\login; 

$p = 'login';
$test2 = '\App\\'.$p.'\\MyClass';

$test = new $test2;
```

Comment: namespace must be first line of file. Isn't it?

Comment: This most certainly works, I use it like this:                                             $class = '\\'.$vendor.'\\'.$application.'\\Router';                                                     return new $class();

Comment: what is the rule of using single or double `\\`s here ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed i don't think there's a rule here \A just happens to not be an escape character. its probably better to always escape the `\` in this case either way

Comment: An explanation of the results would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

**No** they cannot, as mario said.

To encapsulate variables use *Classes*. Polluting the global variable space should definitely be avoided.

- Example

  **`class_dbworker.php:`**

  ```
  class DbWorker
  {
      //properties and method logic
  }

  class DbWorkerData
  {
      public static $hugerelationsmap = array(....);
      public static ....
  }
  ```

  **`mainapp.php:`**

  ```
  include_once 'class_dbworker.php';
  print_r( DbWorkerData::$hugerelationsmap );
  ```
- Example using namespaces

  **`class_dbworker.php:`**

  ```
  namespace staticdata;
  class DbWorker
  {
      //properties and method logic
  }

  class DbWorkerData
  {
      public static $hugerelationsmap = array(....);
      public static ....
  }
  ```

  **`mainapp.php:`**

  ```
  include_once 'class_dbworker.php';

  use staticdata as data;

  print_r( \data\DbWorkerData::$hugerelationsmap );
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can bound a variable to the namespace by  wrapping  the variable inside a function.

```
<?php
 namespace furniture;
// instead of declaring a $version global variable, wrap it inside a function
function version(){
 return "1.3.4";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible because `$MYVARNAME` is still in the global scope. Try following code.

**namespace.php**

```php
<?php
    namespace MYNAME;
    use MYNAME as M;
    const MYVAR   = 'MYVARNAME';

    ${M\MYVAR}    = date('Y');
    echo $MYVARNAME;  // PRINT YEAR
    $MYVARNAME    = 'X';
    echo $MYVARNAME;  // PRINT X
    echo ${M\MYVAR} ; // PRINT X

    include('file.php');
?>
```

**file.php**

```php
<?php
    ${MYNAME\MYVAR}=date('Y');
    echo $MYVARNAME;        // PRINT YEAR
    $MYVARNAME = 'X';
    
    echo $MYVARNAME;        // PRINT X
    echo ${MYNAME\MYVAR};   // PRINT X
    
    include('file2.php');
?>
```

**file2.php**

```php
<?php
    namespace MYNAME2;
    use MYNAME2 as N;
    const MYVAR   = 'MYVARNAME';

    ${N\MYVAR}    = 'Y';
    echo $MYVARNAME;  // PRINT Y
    echo ${MYNAME\MYVAR}; /* PRINT Fatal error: Uncaught Error:
    Undefined constant 'MYNAME2\MYNAME\MYVAR' */
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done - sort of.

This is probably extremely bad and should never be done, but it is possible by using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), and the [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) for namespace.
So a string-variable to name the variable we want to use, like so:

```
<?php
namespace your\namespace;

$varname = __NAMESPACE__.'\your_variablename'; //__NAMESPACE__ is a magic constant
$namespaced_variable = $$varname; //Note the double dollar, a variable variable
?>
```

Comment: The question was `Can PHP namespaces contain variables?` not `Can PHP variables contain namespaces?`

Answer (score 0):

Store Complete classPath in Variable and use after 'new'.

It is very important to realize that because the backslash is used as an escape character within strings, it should always be doubled when used inside a string.

```
<?php
$a = "namespace\\className"; // 'which will print namespace/className'
$obj = new $a;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate ways that can make code more organized:**

**Instead of like \view\header\$links:**

**(1) Backslashes in array key for imaginary nesting**,
Example:

```
$myVar['view\header\links'] = 'value';

// OR use multidimentional arrays

$view['header']['links'] = 'value';
```

**(1.1) Use Global Array**, Example

```
// START - SETUP

define('I', 'mySite_19582730');

// END - SETUP


// Usage:

$GLOBALS[I]['view\header\links'] = 'value';

// OR

$GLOBALS[I]['view__header__links'] = 'value';
```

**(1.1.1) Functions to get & set value in Global Array**

```
function set($key, $val){
    if (is_string($key)) $GLOBALS['site_8619403725'][$key] = $val;
    elseif (is_array($key)){
        foreach($key as $ky => &$vl) {
            $GLOBALS['mySite_19582730'][$vl] = $val;
        }
    }
}

function get($key){
    return @ $GLOBALS['mySite_19582730'][$key];
}

// Usage

set('view\header\search','<div></div>');
set(['view\header\logo','view\header\homeLink'], '<a href=""></a>');
get('view\header\search');
```

**(2) Use __ (double underscores) in variable name to make imaginary nesting**,
Example:

```
$view__header__links = 'value';
```