# Instantiate a new class from a variable's name in a namespace

Tags: php, oop, object, namespaces

Let's say for an instance I have a class:

```
//no namespace
class User { 
    //...
}
```

And I have a variable:

```
$model = 'User';
```

How do I instantiate a `new User` when I am currently in a namespace?

`new $model` works when I'm not in a namespace. But what if I am in a namespace and `User` is not in a namespace.

Something like this doesn't work:

```
namespace Admin;

class Foo {
    function fighter($model)
    {
        return new \$model;
        // syntax error, unexpected '$model'
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the complete Namespace first in a variable and then use it.

```
<?php    
$namespace = '\\'.$model;

return new $namespace
?>
```

Same Topic: [Can PHP namespaces contain variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287315/can-php-namespaces-contain-variables)