# PHP "Scope blocks"

Tags: php, scope

Is it possible to do something similar to the `using` keyword in C# (and probably others) to limit variable scope?  I'm experimenting with database connection patterns, and am currently trying to get this to work:

```
$db = array(
    "server"   =>"localhost",
    "user"     =>"root",
    "pass"     =>"my_password",
    "database" =>"my_database"
);

$pdo = null;

{  // ???  These seem to be completely ignored, no errors, no effect at all
    extract($db);
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $user, $pass);
}

//Do database stuff
```

I'm using `extract`, which is normally a bad idea, so I'm trying to protect whatever it returns where those curly braces are.  In C# I could probably do something *like* `using (extract($db)) { ... }` and whatever `extract` returns would be limited to that scope, but I can't figure out if this is possible in PHP.  I'm not even sure if PHP disposes of variables.

Any insight to this problem is much appreciated!

Comment: Save that all to a function?

Comment: I suppose that would work, since PHP's scope seems to be limited to just functions.  Thanks!

Comment: or use the array notation. at least you'll see from where the variables come. prefer cleaner code.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Normally I would, but PDO's strange syntax of using a string to connect to a DB would result in this: `"mysql:host=".$db["server"].";dbname=".$db["database"]` bleh

Comment: You can use constants too, you won't need functions than

Comment: @Jaxo Or you could utilize a core scripting language feature called interpolation: `"mysql:host=$db[server];dbname=$db[database]"`, less bleh.

Comment: Note: yes, `{` are ignored. In PHP there's no sub-scope. All variables will be visible in the function scope.

Comment: @mario missed braces and quotes there.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `PHP >= 5.3` you can use [Namespaces](http://php.net/namespaces) like this:

```
// per file
namespace App\One
$var = 1;

// or, per block
namespace App\Two {
    $var = 2;
}
```

Then later you can call it like this -- there are other ways as well:

```
echo \App\Two\var;
```

**Update**

Well, it seems that `variables` are not affected by `namespace`.

> Although any valid PHP code can be contained within a namespace, only the following types of code are affected by namespaces: classes (including abstracts and traits), interfaces, functions and constants.

[source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php)

But what you can still do is to use *Constants* instead:

```
namespace App\One;
define('App\One\ABC', 'abc');            // specified namespace
define(__NAMESPACE__ . '\XYZ', 'xyz');   // current namespace -- which is App\One here
```

Comment: I guess that's the only other way to limit scope in PHP...  thank you!

Comment: No. Variables [aren't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287315/can-php-namespaces-contain-variables) bound to namespaes.

Comment: @mario Thanks mario for the correction, I didn't know that. I've updated the answer as well.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of code blocks, IIFEs, or "Immediately invoked function expressions" could be used in PHP too if necessary – they're not just for JavaScript:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression

```php
$x = 1;  // global var
$y = 2;  // global var
echo "x={$x}, y={$y}\n";

// PHP 5.3+
call_user_func(function()use( & $x ){
  $x = 33;  // reference to the global var because use( & $x )
  $y = 44;  // local var
  echo "x={$x}, y={$y}\n";
});

// PHP 7+
(function()use( & $x ){
  $x = 555;  // reference to the global var because use( & $x )
  $y = 666;  // local var
  echo "x={$x}, y={$y}\n";
})();

echo "x={$x}, y={$y}\n";
```

Output:

```
x=1,   y=2    // initial global var values
x=33,  y=44   // inside the first PHP5.3+ iife
x=555, y=666  // inside the second PHP7+ iife
x=555, y=2    // the global variables after executing both
```