# Trying to understand namespace coding

Tags: php, namespaces

I've never really worked with PHP namespacing before and I was reading up on how to use it on the PHP website, including how to include namespace code and non-nonspace (global code) in the one file.

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php

I then tried the below for testing:

```
namespace {

    $bar = 123;

}

namespace moo {

    $bar = 400;

}

namespace {

    echo $bar . "<br>\n";
    //echo moo\$bar . "<br>\n";    

}
```

However what I got back was unexpected..

The output of the above is:

```
400
```

Shouldn't it be `123` since I am not referencing the `moo` namespace? Additionally, if I uncomment the next line I get a PHP syntax error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That form of `{}` after namespaces is new to me, I thought it was just a command at the beginning of a PHP file and I think there is something in the documentation that says variables are always global:http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php

Comment: @JasonSperske Well it said you have to use brackets if you want to use global and namespace code in the same file. My bad about the variable though, which is a pain. :(

Comment: "It is strongly discouraged as a coding practice to combine multiple namespaces into the same file." - From the php.net page you referenced. What are you trying to accomplish here? This is not how traditional namespacing is used.

Comment: @mitch I'm trying to build implement a SSO (single-sign on) with Invision Power Board, but I need to include a bunch of my own code and files inside one of their files but my database $object seems to be getting wiped or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here [Can PHP namespaces contain variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287315/can-php-namespaces-contain-variables) is your answer: *"variables will always exist in the global scope. They are never bound to namespaces."*