# How can I access variables in multiple homonymous files

Tags: php, file, include

PHP: I have several directories with the same file structure in them:

```
root/
 | listConfigContent.php
105/
 | config/
 |  | config.php
 | images/
 | js/
106/
 | config/
 |  | config.php
 | images/
 | js/
107/
 ⋮
```

The config.php files do not use namespaces or classes but contain a couple of variables and constants. What do I have to do to access these variables and constants from the listConfigContent.php? As diskussed here ([Can PHP namespaces contain variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287315/can-php-namespaces-contain-variables)) it is not possible to differentiate them by applied namespaces.

Comment: If they redefine constants: you're out of luck. If talking _only_ variables: you can include those files in a function with limited scope, and set some container value to the output of `get_defined_vars();` after some cleanup.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer seems to be correct and sufficient. Why don't you answer it as an answer, so I can check this question as done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but the answerer didn't use the answer function to answer, so I have to in order to make this Question closable:

"If they redefine constants: you're out of luck. If talking only variables: you can include those files in a function with limited scope, and set some container value to the output of get_defined_vars(); after some cleanup."